# Call a new function after result of user creation in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code :

```
const saltRounds = 10;

let charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

module.exports.addUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let userData = req.body;
    let email = userData.email;


    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length);
      password += charset.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
    }

    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      password = hash;

      userData.password = password;

    });

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json("Server error");
  }
};
```

I get datas from the front end, and then I generate a random password which I add to the userData variable.

What I want now, is to call that function to create a user in database :

```
const newUser = await User.createUser(userData, res);
```

And be able to request the user I have just created from the database to make other stuff just after creation with that :

```
const user = await User.getUser(email);
```

I have tried different things, but every time I have a problem with the order of execution.
For instance, the program tries to get user infos before it is created etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why are you fetching the details again if they're already available when you create user.

```
const newUser = await User.createUser(userData, res);
// newUser has all the values you're trying to fetch
```

bcrypt hash retruns promise if call is not specified

```
module.exports.addUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let userData = req.body;
    let email = userData.email;


    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length);
      password += charset.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
    }

     const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
      if(hash) {
      password = hash;
      userData.password = password;
     }
      //then the create user promise code

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json("Server error");
  }
};
```

That's not how promise works. to work with the promise sequentially
you can do something like this

```
let newUserData = null
Promise.all([ User.createUser(userData, res), User.getUser(email);])
        .then((result) =>  newUserData = result[0]);
         // the result will be an array the 1st element will be the response of User.createUser(userData, res) and respective other
```

let me know if this helps!

Comment: If I put the createUser function after the Bcrypt function, the user is not created because the password is null. I assume that createUser is run before Bcrypt

Comment: @Myrmelomade some changes. tell me if this works.

Comment: It works BUT i have a problem xD. When I console.log newUser, it is undifined. What I wanted to do by the fetch is to get the id of the user we've just created, how can I get it ?

Comment: Made changes, marked it as answered if that answer's question. if you have another question, please create a new question